# mdi icons not working on a fresh installation of Vue3 + vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am learning vue3 and vuetify and I am trying to create my application by first installing Vue with Vite and then adding Vuetify using the following commands:

```
npm create vue@latest
npm i --save vuetify
```

However, when I try to add an icon with the following code:

```
<v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-export</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

I can hover over the button but I cannot see the icon.

I have already installed the mdi icons pack using:

```
npm install --save material-design-icons-iconfont
```

and I have added the following to my `main.js`

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    icons: {
        defaultSet: 'mdi',
        aliases,
        sets: {
          mdi,
        },
    },
    ssr: true,
})
```

Comment: Have you added the CSS import (as described [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#mdi-css))?

Comment: That was what I was missing, thanks! Add it as an answer to this question so that I can accept it.

Comment: Oh, that's nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the icon font, you have to import the CSS, too (as described [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#mdi-css)):

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
```